# PHP built-in web server .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, web, server

I always start my server in cmd in directory, where I want root like so:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Everything works, except for my .htaccess file. When I copy my project to htdocs, it works just fine.

Do you have any configuration tips or something, that can solve this? :)

Comment: `.htaccess` style files are an implementation of the apache http server. They do not make any sense for other types of http servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's built in web server does not support .htaccess-es,because those are a part of the Apache web server.